# Is it best practice to combine MySQL data tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am considering changing a database scheme to reduce the number of tables. I have several tables that contain different-yet-similar data, and am wondering if it is best practice to leave it this way, or if there would be complications with combining them.

For example, let's say I have the following two tables:

```
Table `status`

`status_id` | `status_text`
---------------------------
1           | Open
2           | Closed
3           | On Hold

Table `type`

`type_id`   | `type_text`
---------------------------
1           | Regular Work
2           | Advanced Work
3           | Warranty Work
```

Would it be advantageous to combine these into a table, such as the following?

```
Table `text`

`id`        | `type`        | `text`
-------------------------------------------
1           | 1             | Open
2           | 1             | Closed
3           | 1             | On Hold
1           | 2             | Regular Work
2           | 2             | Advanced Work
3           | 2             | Warranty Work
```

The `type` column would correlate to PHP constants representing the data set type.

I currently have probably 6 tables with data in this exact scheme. It just bugs me that they are so similar, and each only holds 2-5 rows. I really want to combine them as I have above, but am not sure if there would be complications down the road from it, or if it is breaking best-practices.

I do realize the `id` column would conflict and would not be candidate for a primary key, but it would be a unique key along with `type` to prevent collisions. I am not worried about auto_increment, as these tables are managed manually.

Also another thing to keep in mind is that these tables are involved in several JOINS. I don't see it complicating the JOINs much more other than adding one more condition to the ON clause.

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, it seemed a hard subject to look up, as I am not posing a common question about selecting the data, but rather the scheme.

Comment: Do you have items in another table that have a status and a type? If so, columns in that third table that reflect that item's status and type, while leaving your other tables as is would be my preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are pros and cons, and it often comes down to personal preference.  I personally prefer multiple disparate lookup tables (since each one corresponds to a different entity definition within my domain, despite being composed of coincidentally similar primitive types).  Others sometimes prefer the single "super lookup" table for the reasons you state.

One approach I've often seen is to have something like this:

```
LookUp
----------
ID
LookUpTypeID
Value
DisplayText
etc.

LookUpType
----------
ID
Name
```

This provides a fairly straightforward way to organize your lookup values into the single structure.  And if you ever find yourself wanting to separate out the types to "mimic" the disparate tables (for example, if a developer like me joins your team and makes a lot of noise), you can always create views based on the types and use those in queries.

There's nothing inherently wrong with multiple small tables.  If the data they contain genuinely *means* something different then I would argue that it should be separated.  The conceptual meaning of the entities in the domain is *far* more important than the data types of which they're composed.

And multiple small tables makes little difference to the database engine.  It's pretty optimized, you're not doing it any favors by combining the tables.  In fact, you may find that your queries become slightly more obtuse over time as you do this.  The meaning of the data being queried from the database starts to get clouded by implementation details within the tables.  You can *mitigate* this by adding views to logically separate the data again, but if you find yourself needing to do that then why combine it in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and reasoning on both sides of the argument. Wouldn't it be interesting if SQL supported OOP? That may be where my original thinking on this matter stemmed from in terms of consolidation. I will accept this answer mostly due to this quote: "The conceptual meaning of the entities in the domain is far more important than the data types of which they're composed." - Very good point, in conjunction with the argument that it will kill the meaning of the data.

Comment: @Demonslay335: There are databases out there which are more geared toward object-oriented models rather than relational models.  You may want to look into the various "NoSQL" databases (document databases, object databases, etc.).  You can do some measure of "supertyping" and "subtyping" in SQL, but it's not an inheritance/interface model like most programming languages offer.

Comment: Combining tables also means that you have to add an extra field when adding values to the table and to add an extra field when selecting. You are likely to create a query which links to the same table several times, each time differentiated by a different 'type' qualifier. Whilst the database engine can probably handle this without difficulty, the person writing the queries will probably become confused. So, it's not a good idea to combine the tables.

Answer (score 4):

No. This is not OK. You're going backwards in proper database design/normalization and needlessly obfuscating your data.

Sure you *can* do this, but you'll regret doing it at some point in the future. Do you really want to be presented with a question like: "Hey Demonslay335, what Text type is this work type in the Text type table? Can you type that out for me? Typey-type type type."

Saying a word enough times turns it into gibberish, just like meta-typing your data.

Comment: I am always under the assumption that splitting the tables to minimize the number of columns that one table has, using data integrity and Data Relationships to ensure data is protected.

Comment: Thank you for the major point about obfusticating the data, I now see that is very true.

Answer (score 1):

If you have different constraints, you should use separate tables, even if the data "looks" similar.

For example, you can define FOREIGN KEYs towards different referencing tables very naturally if the lookup tables are separate.

The same would be harder to do if you put everything in the same table. Purely declarative way would be to migrate the `type` along the FK and then have a CHECK in the referencing table to ensure the correct type. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't enforce CHECKs, so you'd need to enforce the right type through triggers or (God forbid) application logic.

Comment: Good point with the foreign keys. I have not personally used a foreign key before, as keys are probably my weakest part of database logic, but I can see the issues that would arise should I choose to implement them at some point.

Comment: @Demonslay335 You should really familiarize yourself with foreign keys as they are a fundamental aspect of database design. Foreign key is not a really a "key", it just references a key from another table. It's a kind of a "pointer" that can never "dangle" (to use C/C++ parlance). BTW, the same problem exists for other kinds of constraints as well - for example what if you have a CHECK that makes sense in one lookup table but not the other (assuming you use a DBMS that actually supports CHECKs)?

Comment: ... At the very least, you'd have to make it dependent on `type`, making it less clear. And depending on the kind of CHECK, it could actually be very hard to make it correct **and** performant in the *concurrent* environment.

Comment: I definitely will start looking into using foreign keys, thanks for the suggestion. I am inheriting this database scheme, which is making it more and more scary to make alterations after the system has been in use for 5+ years, but it will definitely, if anything else, help me in further projects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reasons to combine the tables into one table.

One thing i would consider is using an [enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html) column. Where you have columns which are foreign keys referencing `status`, instead make them enums. You can then dispense with the table entirely. This results in a simpler schema. However, it has some weaknesses (some go so far as to call it [evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/)); for instance, if you use the same enumeration in several places, you have no guarantee that all the definitions are the same, and there is a risk that as the database evolves, they will get out of sync. Still, we use them quite a lot in our schema, and haven't really felt any pain from that.

Comment: Interesting proposition. I don't believe it would be best to go with an enum column simply due to the fact that the data is dynamic and differs between installations of the software I am developing. Otherwise, I could definitely see that as being tempting. I personally haven't like enums, even in C++. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Ah, in that case, no an enum definitely isn't suitable.