# Best Practice Overall: Multiple Tables or a Type ID?

Tags: database-design

I got this thought while designing a database for a program that keeps track of goods being moved into and out of a location. Either I could have a single table keeping track of each relocation, with a boolean field denoting whether the object is moving in or out. Or, I could have two nearly identical tables for the two different directions respectively.

My question is:
**Is it generally advantageous to split a table into 2 or more tables, based on a field that would have limited options?**

Advantages I see in splitting:

- Avoids conditional statements.
- Easier when differences between tables develop in the future.
- Better performance on individual tables, because tables are smaller.

Advantages I see in combining:

- Avoids code duplication.
- Easier when identical behaviors are added in the future.
- Better performance in cases where data would have to be retrieved from multiple tables.
- Prevents wild growth of tables.

Both approaches look powerful under different circumstances. But what I'm wondering is, if you can't tell which advantages you'll need, which of these approaches would be the best practice? Is one straight-up better overall? If not, what would cause the least pain if you're wrong?

Or is there a different design approach that specifically handles this dilemma? As I'm finishing up this question, I'm thinking it's also an option to store the identical data in a single table, then introducing extra tables specifically for the differences. Yet this approach seems maybe too complex to apply as a default.

I found another related question, asking it the opposite way: [Is it best practice to combine MySQL data tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225023/is-it-best-practice-to-combine-mysql-data-tables). However, I find that this post puts a lot of emphasis on merging together entirely unrelated tables that all happen to represent a single text field. And this is what the answers mainly end up focusing on.

I'm talking about tables that are so similar, that they are basically the same data type, but with a difference that causes them to be used in profoundly different ways.

Other examples that come to mind:

- User account types that use a website in very different ways.
- Product types that may have unique attributes.
- Job types that perform very different types of work.

Answer (score 0):

I might've been too soon at asking the question, since I figured out the answer now and it's a bit of an anti-climax, but maybe it can be useful to others searching the internet with the same dilemma.

When unsure which is the best approach between the two, it's possible to get the best of both worlds. You can take all the data that makes these tables the same, and make a single generic table for that. In my case, a "cargo". Then, there can be multiple different tables that refer to this generic table for their data. They could even be empty aside from the reference to the generic table.

Possible approaches:

1. Start with only the generic table, add the more specific bonus tables in the future as needed. Probably best if you don't know whether you will treat the variants different in the future.
2. Start with the generic table, plus empty tables referring to the loads, that can have specialized columns added in the future as needed. Probably best if you are already going to treat the variants differently.